# Issue on Quering Database Using jQuery Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.goproweb.ca/E2O/assets/econo.php) and let me know why I am getting empty array?
I have a jquery ajac request as:

```
   $( "#appinfo" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {
    var eTraget = $(".opacity").html().replace(/\D/g,'');
    var senario = current;
    if(qtype =="econo"){
    var col = senario +"_"+eTraget;

    var data='column='+col;
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"assets/econo.php",
    data:data,
    dataType : 'json',       
    success:function(html) {
    coords = html;
    console.log(data);
    st = map.set();
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        var circle = map.circle(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 6);
        st.push(circle);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

and  econo.php as:

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$collm = $_POST['column'];
$query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  econo WHERE".$collm."=1";
$results = $con->query($query);
$return = array();
if($results) {
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return[] = array((float)$row['x'],(float)$row['y']);
}
}
$con->close();
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

As you can see I console.log(data); and the console display the result like `column=ce_3000` but the `$collm = $_POST['column'];` is empty because whrn tried to dump it I just got an empty []. Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: how about `$query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1";`

Comment: Thanks Abhik, that was the issue

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.